# SPSS Syntax: set minimum count for frequencies or select cases

Tags: syntax, spss

Background:
I'm working on an individual response dataset which data I'll aggregate up to the municipality level. However, I only want to work with the aggregated data that derives from more than 20 individual cases.

Question: 
How can I use the variable for the municipal level to count how many in-variable unique cases that exist, *excluding cases with a count of less than 20?*

I know of a few workarounds, using the aggregate function, but also count in Excel. However, can this be done easier in syntax, and before aggregating the data?

Will appreciate any help and suggestions!

Comment: Can you give an example? It is difficult to figure out exactly what you want given the description.

Comment: AGGREGATE (+ `mode=addvariables`) command can add the aggregated variables to the original dataset, so you can keep working on it _with the new variables_, and don't need to move to an aggregated dataset.

Answer (score 1):

When you run AGGREGATE, choose the N as one of the statistics.  Then you can use SELECT IF in the aggregated dataset to select only the units with at least the minimum N.  You might want, though, to think about whether the small-N units are systematically different in a way that might affect your analysis.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to aggregate your data, you can do this by using the LAG-Funktion and some sorting (depending on the size of your data set this might take some time).

First of all you have to make sure, that all cases belonging to the same municipality are in one block of cases.

```
SORT CASES BY municipality.
```

Now you can count the number of individuals in each municipality using the LAG-Function.

```
COMPUTE n_mun = 1.
IF (municipality = LAG(municipality)) n_mun = LAG(n_mun) + 1.
EXECUTE.
```

The total number of indivivuals in each municipality is now stored in the last case of each municipality (n_mun). If you want to copy this value into the other cases of the same municipality you have to sort again with n_mun in descending order, so the highest value is on top. (unless IBM decides to include a reverse LAG-Command into SPSS).

```
SORT CASES municipality n_mun(D).
IF (municipality = LAG(municipality)) n_mun = LAG(n_mun).
EXECUTE.
```